# How to avoid ordering an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, shiny

I really dont know anything about javascript but I had to use some in a shiny (R) application.
The application allows users to select columns from a table in Shiny. This table then uses a javascript callback, part of which gets the column indices and places them in an array. The array seems to order the indices in number order whereas I need the order to be maintained as the user has selected the columns. How can I avoid the indices being ordered by number order? Here is the code:

```
  output$mergedTable = DT::renderDT({
    if (!is.null(RV3$data)) {  



      RV3$data[["Select"]]<-paste0('<input type="checkbox" name="row_selected" value="Row',1:nrow(RV3$data),'"><br>')

      RV3$data[["Actions"]]<-
      paste0('
             <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary delete" id=delete_',1:nrow(RV3$data),'>Delete</button>
             </div>
             ')
    }


 datatable(RV3$data,escape=F, extensions = c("Select","Buttons"), selection = "none",callback = JS( "var ncols = table.columns().count();",
                                                                                      "var tbl = table.table().node();",
                                                                                      "var tblID = $(tbl).closest('.datatables').attr('id');",
                                                                                      "table.on('click', 'tbody td', function(){",
                                                                                      "  // if the column is selected, deselect it:",
                                                                                      "  if(table.column(this, {selected: true}).length){",
                                                                                      "    table.column(this).deselect();",
                                                                                      "  // otherwise, select the column unless it's among the last two columns:",
                                                                                      "  } else if([ncols-1, ncols-2].indexOf(table.column(this).index()) === -1){",
                                                                                      "    table.column(this).select();",
                                                                                      "  }",
                                                                                      "  // send selected columns to Shiny",
                                                                                      "  var indexes = table.columns({selected:true}).indexes();",
                                                                                      "  var indices = Array(indexes.length);",
                                                                                      "  for(var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i){",
                                                                                      "    indices[i] = indexes[i];",
                                                                                      "  }",
                                                                                      "  Shiny.setInputValue(tblID + '_columns_selected', indices);",
                                                                                     " var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('row_selected');",
                                                                                    "  var checkboxesChecked = [];",
                                                                                     " for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {",
                                                                                    "    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {",
                                                                                       "   checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i].value);",
                                                                                    "    }",
                                                                                   "   }",
                                                                                     " Shiny.onInputChange('checked_rows',checkboxesChecked);",
                                                                                      "});"),

           options = list(
             scrollX = TRUE,
             scrollY = TRUE,
             pageLength = 200,
             select = "api",
             dom = 'Bfrtip',
             buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print','colvis'))
           )


  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to manually track the columns as they are selected by maintaining your own list.

```
var tblID = $(tbl).closest('.datatables').attr('id');
// below the tblID declaration add your array declaration.
var selectedIndices = [];

// later on in your onclick callback:   
if(table.column(this, {selected: true}).length){
    table.column(this).deselect();
    selectedIndices.splice(selectedIndices.indexOf(
        table.column(this).index()), 1);
} else if([ncols-1, ncols-2].indexOf(table.column(this).index()) === -1){
    table.column(this).select();
    selectedIndices.push(table.column(this).index());
}

// then use the indices list you have been maintaining instead of calling
// table.columns({selected:true}).indexes()
Shiny.setInputValue(tblID + '_columns_selected', selectedIndices);
```

Comment: You can read about splice here -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice